# How to redirect everyone but me on Development Subdomain with .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a development subdomain which is http://dev.example.com, how can I stop this website being indexed in search engines and if someone types in that link, how do I redirect them to the main site?

I tried doing it with .htaccess but when I added this line of code it showed that page on the index.html file and messed up the page:

RewriteRule .? http://www.google.com [L]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you're the only one using your IP-address, you could redirect based on that. Other options include user-authentication, requiring a known client ssl certificate, and others. This should also keep the robots of your dev site, but you could supply them with a robots.txt which denies indexing anything.

Comment: Please ensure to show what you have tried so we can see and possibly fix mistakes you have made if not suggest better alternatives

Answer (score 1):

```
$your_ip = '';

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' != $your_ip){
    header("location:".$your_redirect_url);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need this code in your .htaccess:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from aa.bb.cc.dd
Allow from mm.nn.pp.qq
```

Replace `aa.bb.cc.dd`, `mm.nn.pp.qq` etc with your own IP address. This will not only block all search bots it will block all unwanted visitors to your dev site.